# convert column to row in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a question, is there any method that convert colum to row.
for example,I have a table like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE mytable(u_id, month, offer, revenue) as
SELECT 1, 'January', 'Offer_1', 45  FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'February','Offer_2', 40  FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'March'   ,'Offer_1', 35  FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'January' ,'Offer_2', 40  FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'February','Offer_3', 40  FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'March'   ,'Offer_1', 50  FROM dual;
```

and my expected table is

(There should be one row per user)

| u_id | january_offer | january_revenue | february_offer | february_revenue | march_offer | march_revenue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Offer_1 | 45 | Offer_2 | 40 | Offer_1 | 35 |
| 2 | Offer_2 | 40 | Offer_3 | 40 | Offer_1 | 50 |

I tried:

```sql
SELECT t1.u_id,
       t1.january_offer,
       t1.january_revenue,
       t2.february_offer,
       t2.february_revenue,
       t3.march_offer,
       t3.march_revenue
  FROM (SELECT u_id, offer AS january_offer, 
                     revenue AS january_revenue
          FROM mytable
         WHERE month = 'January') t1
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT u_id,
                    offer   AS february_offer,
                    revenue AS february_revenue
               FROM mytable t1
              WHERE month = 'February') t2
    ON t1.u_id = t2.u_id
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT u_id, offer AS march_offer, 
                          revenue AS march_revenue
               FROM mytable t1
              WHERE month = 'March') t3
    ON t2.u_id = t3.u_id
```

but,real, I have lots of data and a long SQL script and this method aggravates my script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what `PIVOT` is designed for:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   package
PIVOT (
  MAX(offer) AS offer, MAX(revenue) AS revenue
  FOR month IN ( 'January' AS january, 'February' AS feburary, 'March' AS march )
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE package (U_id, month, offer,revenue) AS
SELECT 1, 'January',  'offer_1', 45 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'February', 'offer_2', 40 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'March',    'offer_1', 35 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'January',  'offer_2', 40 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'February', 'offer_3', 40 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'March',    'offer_1', 50 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | U_ID | JANUARY_OFFER | JANUARY_REVENUE | FEBURARY_OFFER | FEBURARY_REVENUE | MARCH_OFFER | MARCH_REVENUE |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | offer_1 | 45 | offer_2 | 40 | offer_1 | 35 |
> | 2 | offer_2 | 40 | offer_3 | 40 | offer_1 | 50 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=eaa3897511a3633f4560980224a51fc6)*

Comment: Though other answers are correct but this is the shortest one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation along with **`CASE..WHEN`** expressions such as

```sql
SELECT u_id,
       MAX(CASE WHEN month = 'January' THEN offer END) AS january_offer,
       MAX(CASE WHEN month = 'January' THEN revenue END) AS january_revenue,
       MAX(CASE WHEN month = 'February' THEN offer END) AS february_offer,
       MAX(CASE WHEN month = 'February' THEN revenue END) AS february_revenue,
       MAX(CASE WHEN month = 'March' THEN offer END) AS march_offer,
       MAX(CASE WHEN month = 'March' THEN revenue END) AS march_revenue
  FROM t
 GROUP BY u_id
```

or by using **`DECODE()`** function such as

```sql
SELECT u_id,
       MAX(DECODE (month , 'January', offer)) AS january_offer,
       MAX(DECODE (month , 'January', revenue)) AS january_revenue,
       MAX(DECODE (month , 'February', offer)) AS february_offer,
       MAX(DECODE (month , 'February', revenue)) AS february_revenue,
       MAX(DECODE (month , 'March', offer)) AS march_offer,
       MAX(DECODE (month , 'March', revenue)) AS march_revenue
  FROM t
 GROUP BY u_id
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=82026bff7d23fd868c9320758cd25d07)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

An alternative pattern that might be more efficient is to use a case expression:

```
SELECT t1.u_id
     , CASE month WHEN 'January' then offer END AS january_offer
     , CASE month WHEN 'January' then revenue END AS january_revenue
     , CASE month WHEN 'February' then offer END AS february_offer
     , ...
```

From there you can use an aggregate function to eliminate null rows:

```
SELECT u_id
     , MAX(january_offer) AS january_offer
     , MAX(january_revenue) AS january_revenue
     , MAX(february_offer) AS february_offer
     , ...
FROM (  
    SELECT t1.u_id
         , CASE month WHEN 'January' then offer END AS january_offer
         , CASE month WHEN 'February' then offer END AS february_offer
         , ...
) AS t
GROUP BY u_id
```

In general, this kind of operation is better handled in the presentation layer of the application than in the database layer.